# How to use Log4j2 Spring Profile Arbiter in YAML configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I'm trying to get the [Spring Profile Arbiter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-spring-boot/index.html) working. According to the documentation you can place an arbiter almost anywhere:

> So an Arbiter could encapsulate something as simple as a single property declaration or a whole set of Appenders or Loggers.

Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't provide any example code how this can be done in modern yaml-config files. This is what I have at the moment:

```yaml
Configuration:
  name: Default
  //...

  Properties:
    Property:
      - name: log-dir
        value: "./logs"
      - name: log-file-name
        value: "logfile"
      - name: log-file-ext
        value: "log"

      - name: connection-factory-method
        value: "getDbConnection"

      SpringProfile:
        name: development
        - name: connection-factory-method
          value: "getDbConnection4dev"

      - name: con-pattern-logger
        value: "%-50.50c{1.}"

  //...
```

Sadly, not working as expected. Played for a while, but couldn't find a working solution. All I get are initialization errors.

I am grateful for any information that could help me get ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your configuration each YAML object represents a Log4j2 component.

The type of object (short plugin name) to instantiate must be provided as `type` property of the YAML object. If no such property exist, the key associated to the object is used.

To define a [`SpringProfileArbiter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-spring-boot/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/spring/boot/SpringProfileArbiter.html) component that contains a [`Property`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Property.html) component you can either use:

```yaml
key1:
  type: SpringProfile
  name: development
  property1:
    type: Property
    name: connection-factory-method
    value: "getDbConnection4dev"
```

or

```yaml
SpringProfile:
  name: development
  Property:
    name: connection-factory-method
    value: "getDbConnection4dev"
```

You can use arrays if you want to define multiple components of the same type.

**Remark:** if your application runs under the "development" profile, the "connection-factory-method" property will be defined **twice**. To prevent this you can use [`SelectArbiter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/arbiters/SelectArbiter.html) and [`DefaultArbiter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/arbiters/DefaultArbiter.html) to provide the equivalent of an `if ... else` clause:

```yaml
Select:
  SpringProfile:
    name: development
    Property:
      name: connection-factory-method
      value: "getDbConnection4dev"
  DefaultArbiter:
    Property:
      name: connection-factory-method
      value: "getDbConnection"
```